# Proving $\|f(x)-f(a)\|\le M\| x-a\|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

**Theorem(1): (M.V.T for real valued functions)**

Let $V \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be open. Suppose $ f: V \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable on $V$. If $x, a\in V$ then there is $c\in L(x;a)$ such that $f(x)-f(a)=\nabla f(c)\cdot (x-a)$

---

**Theorem(2): (M.V.T for vector valued functions)**

Let $V \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be open. Suppose $ f: V \to \Bbb R^m$ is differentiable on $V$. If $x, a\in V$ and $L(x;a)\subseteq V$ then given any **u** $\in \Bbb R^m$there is $c\in L(x;a)$ such that (**u**)$(f(x)-f(a))=$ (**u**) $(Df(c)\cdot (x-a))$

---

**The statement:**

Let $V \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be open. Let $H$ be compact subset of $V$ and suppose that $ f: V \to \Bbb R^m$ is $C^1$ on $V$. If $E\subset H$ is convex, then there is a constant $M$ such that $\| f(x)-f(a)\|\le M\| x-a\| \forall x,a \in E.$

---

I need to prove that the statement by **using the theorem(1)** -*not using the theorem (2)*-

Please show me thank you:)

Comment: There probably are two typos in the last inequality.

Comment: And in the title also. ($x \mapsto a$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: apply theorem 1 to each component of $f=(f_1,\dots,f_m)$.

**Edit: elaborating**

Clearly, each component $f_i:V\to\mathbb R$ is $\mathcal C^1$ on $V$. Thus, we can apply th. 1 to say that $\exists c_i\in L(a,x)$ (note that $c_i\in E$, thanks to convexity), such that $f_i(x)-f_i(a)=\nabla f_i (c)\cdot(x-a)$. This leads to say that $$|f_i(x)-f_i(a)|\le \|\nabla f_i (c)\|\|x-a\|.$$  As $\nabla f_i$ is a continuous function on a compact, there's a supremum of $\|\nabla f_i\|$. Let
$$M_i=\sup_{c\in E}\|\nabla f_i(c)\|,$$
then $$\forall x,a \in E\quad |f_i(x)-f_i(a)|\le M_i\|x-a\|.$$
Then again, let $$M=\frac{1}{\sqrt m}\max_{i=1..n} M_i, so$$
$$\|f(x)-f(a)\|^2 = \sum_i |f_i(x)-f_i(a)|^2\le \frac{M^2}{m} \sum_i  \| x - a \|^2 =M^2\| x - a \|^2.$$

Comment: I would want to do, but I could not do. Please can you show step by step. Thank you so much.

Comment: (+1) Just note: We proved this for Euclidean norm, but that is not problem because all norms on finite-dimensional vector spaces are equivalent.

Comment: Yeah! I understand well. Thank you:))

Answer (score 2):

Let $f=(f_1,...f_m).$Since $E$ is convex, for any $x,y\in E$, $L(x;y) \subset E \subset K .$ As your given $f$ is $C^1$ on $V$, Note that $\nabla f_i$ is continuous on $V$ for each $i$.Choose $M'=max_{1\leq i\leq m}[ {\sup_{x\in K}||\nabla f_i(x)||}]$.As $K$ is compact subset of $V$, $M'$ will be finite.And for this $M'$ clearly $||f(x)-f(y)||\space = \space (\sum _{i}||f_i(x)-f_i(y)||^2)^{1/2}\space \leq \space [\sum _{i}||\nabla f_i(c_{x,y})||^2]^{1/2}.||x-y|| \space \space $ $
\leq \space m^{1/2}M'||x-y|| \forall x,y \in E.$

Now chose your correct $M$.